# Can a function be differentiable while having a discontinuous derivative?

Tags: limits, functions, derivatives, continuity

Recently I came across functions like $x^2\sin(1/x)$ and $x^3\sin(1/x)$ where the derivatives were discontinuous. Can there exist a function whose derivative is not conitnuous, and yet the function is differentiable? If yes, please provide some examples.

Comment: Your second example has a continuous derivative, actually. But the first is an example of an everywhere differentiable function whose derivative is discontinuous.

Comment: What is your definition of differentiable?

Comment: It's possible using some piece-wise definitions, at least. See [here](http://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_of_differentiable_function_need_not_be_continuous)

Comment: As an aside, see [Volterra's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra's_function).

Answer (score 1):

The functions you mentioned are in fact differentiable, so you can use them as examples.