# How differentiable is the function $g(x) = \sum_n 2^{-n} f(x-r_n)$ where $f(x)=x^2 \sin\frac1{x}$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, examples-counterexamples

This is an auxiliary enquiry (something like it may well be already discussed on MSE, but I haven't found it) resulting from a feeling of unease provoked by the question of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1266552/can-a-function-be-differentiable-while-having-a-discontinuous-derivative). Taking the example of 
$$f(x)=x^2 \sin\frac1{x}$$ 
let us suppose $r_n$ is an enumeration of the rationals in $(0,1)$, and form the function $g$ defined on $(0,1)$:
$$
g(x) = \sum_n 2^{-n} f(x-r_n)
$$
I guess that $g$ is well-defined and continuous, but is not uniformly continuous. what can be said about the differentiability of $g$?

Comment: *How differentiable is this function?* - You mean on the Holden scale ? :-$)$

Comment: a nicely-judged comment ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $g,$ which can actually be defined for $x\in \mathbb {R},$ is uniformly continuous on every compact subset of $\mathbb {R},$ and is differentiable everywhere.

Proof: $f$ is continuous everywhere, hence is bounded on compact sets. Thus the sum converges uniformly to $g$ on compact sets by the Weierstrass M-test. As the summands are all continuous, $g$ is continuous on compact sets, hence $g$ is uniformly continuous on compact sets.

As for differentiability, note that each summand is differentiable on $\mathbb {R}.$ Furthermore, on any compact set, the derivatives of the summands are uniformly bounded. Thus the series of derivatives converges uniformly on compact subsets $\mathbb {R},$ again by Weierstrass M. The standard theorem on differentiation and uniform convergence can now be invoked to give

$$g'(x) = \sum_n 2^{-n} f'(x-r_n), \,\, x\in \mathbb {R}.$$

Comment: thank you. your answer will help me to study this further. i restricted the definition to a bounded set as i was anxious about enumerations of $\mathbb{Q}$ with $|r_{n_j}| \gt 2^{n_j}$ for some subsequence $n_j$. is this a "removable singularity" in my (rather limited) understanding of these trickier situations?

Comment: No, restricting the $r_n$'s as you did is perfectly natural. However, we could be completely reckless with the $r_n$'s if we set $f(x) = \frac {x^2}{1+x^2}\sin (1/x),$ whose derivative is still discontinuous at $0.$